# Quiz. Condition without condition keyword?

Tags: conditional-statements

Is there any other way of creating a conditional execution?

way 1 : the obvious using "if"

```
    if(condition)
    {
      doThis();
    }
    else
    {
      doThat();
    }
```

way 2: other direct approach using  "?"

```
(condition) ? doThis():doThat();
```

way 3: this using "while"

```
  boolean test=condition;
  while(test) 
    {doThis(); break;}
  while(!test)
    {doThat(); break;}
```

way 4: this using "for"

```
  for(;condition;)   { doThis(); break; }
  for(;!condition;)  { doThat(); break; }
```

way 5: this using "switch"

```
  switch(condition) { case 0: doThat();break; default: doThis();break;}
```

Any other ideas?
Is there a possibility of choice execution path without a condition keyword?

This is intended to be a community wiki

Comment: "Community wiki" is not a Get Out of Jail Free Card. And it seems like you forgot to pick a language.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes some quizzes aren't downvoted, then it depends on how funny are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use shortcut logic.

```
boolean b = (condition && doThis()) || (!condition && doThat());
```

Comment: Does this not assume that `doThis()` and `doThat` return something?

Comment: I don't think you even need the assignment.

Comment: Yes, it does, because the compiler compiles everything regardless of `condition`. Code that doesn't execute still has to compile.

Answer (score 2):

this would do the trick:

```
x.play();
alert("this gets alerted if x is defined and has a method play()");
```

Comment: it lacks of two things, 1-doesn't evaluate a boolean condition, 2-doesn't let you execute one or another method

Comment: ok, but, there is a condition with 2 possible outcomes, wich determines if my second statement gets executed or not; smells a bit boolean to me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the condition gives zero or one:

```
typedef void (*fn)(void);
fn options[2] = { doThis, doThat };
(*option[condition]) ();
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways, one way is to "load" code/routine into memory in some type (array, vector) and then depending on user action load that code and run it.  A short pseudo example:

Say you are programming a game, somewhere do you have something like this:

```
if(IS_KEY_PRESSED_DOWN('A')) {
 //code to move left
}
if(IS_KEY_PRESSED_DOWN('D')) {
 //code to move right
}
```

Instead of having this can you make a map/array:

```
function moveLeft() {
  //move left
}
function moveRight() {
  //move left
}

actions['A'] = moveLeft;
actions['D'] = moveRight;

for(var key in keys_pressed) { 
  actions[key](); //there the variable "actions" is an array of functions.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java .. you, err, you asked for it:

```
static class TrueException extends RuntimeException {}

static class FalseException extends RuntimeException {}

private static Map<Boolean, RuntimeException> map = new HashMap<Boolean, RuntimeException>();
static {
    map.put(true, new TrueException());
    map.put(false, new FalseException());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        throw map.get(condition);
    } catch (TrueException te) {
        doThis();
    } catch (FalseException fe) {
        doThat();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use object oriented behavior and polymorphism to remove conditional statements. This can be implemented with any number of behavioral design patterns. State and Template Method are two that I use frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could have a list of labels and using the infamous goto statement. And i is a index

```
goto labels[i]
```

Comment: this is accually a switch case statement. It takes the label on the i:th index and goto that label. For example if lables = {start,loop,end} and you use goto labels[1] the programm will branch to the loop lable

Comment: it's a list of labels (addresses to which you can jump). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Label_(computer_science)
Here's the wikipedia page about labels